# Memoization in react (for example reselect) where thes memoized values are kept?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

Memoization in react (for example reselect) where thes memoized values are kept? Some cookie, local storage?

Comment: The memoized value will be stored in memory since it will be gone by the page refresh.

Comment: JavaScript code gets saved in the memory of the browser process, not like cookies which will be save on the hard disk

Comment: @adel so in session storage?

Comment: @heisenberg7584 - no. `const x = 1`. Sets a variable that is stored "in memory" that is not in session storage. Your application code contains data, variables, functions, etc that is stored "in memory" - it exists only within the browser process.

Answer (score 1):

Reselect stores its memoized values in memory.

Here is reselect's [`defaultMemoize` source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/d8fad12f35934ab2b3dd80ba8e702762d554a37e/src/index.js#L23) where the variable `lastResult` points to the last returned result.